# check if a particular location falls on the path between two locations

Tags: android, api, geocoding, google-directions-api

How to check if a particular location (LatLng) falls on the path connecting between two locations already given.

The path between these locations is fetched using the google direction API specified for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using this Google maps Open source library [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

There are methods like

- [isLocationOnPath](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L158)
- [isLocationOnEdge](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L139)